# Checking files on a remote folder through Windows app

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

I am using VS-2008 [C#] with .NET 3.5 SP1 installed.

I am writing an auto-update utility for my application. I want to connect via FTP and search for the files on the remote server. I want to check the versions of the local and remote file. As expected, if new files are on server, display alert.

I started with following code:

```
FtpWebRequest ftpRequest = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://ftp.mysite.com//myFiles");
try
{
    ftpRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("new user", "new password");
    ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetDateTimestamp;
    DateTime FtpFileLastModified = ((FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse()).LastModified;
}
catch (Exception)
{
    throw;
}
```

I want to know which is a recommended method to perform this type of task in `.NET 3.5 SP1`. Please illustrate with a little code.

Comment: As an aside, you shouldn't catch an exception you're just going to re-throw. You should either deal with the exception, or not catch it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use FileSystemWatcher Class-
Listens to the file system change notifications and raises events when a directory, or file in a directory, changes.